# VBA returns #REF! when Pasting Values

Tags: vba, excel

I need VBA to copy and paste values of a range, from A15:I17 to A14:I16. Here is my code:

```
Range("A15:I17").Copy
    Range("A14").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

It returns the values as #REF! when using the code, but when I manually preform this action it pastes perfect.

Here is an example of the formula that is in the cells being pasted:

```
Range("B17").Formula = "=INDEX('Focus Data Edited'!$G:$G,MATCH(1e99,'Focus Data Edited'!$G:$G))"
Range("C17").Formula = "=(D17+E17)"
Range("D17").Formula = "=INDEX('Focus Data Edited'!$H:$H,MATCH(1e99,'Focus Data Edited'!$H:$H))"
Range("E17").Formula = "=INDEX('Focus Data Edited'!$I:$I,MATCH(1e99,'Focus Data Edited'!$I:$I))"
Range("F17").Formula = "=INDEX('Focus Data Edited'!$J:$J,MATCH(1e99,'Focus Data Edited'!$J:$J))"
Range("G17").Formula = "=INDEX('Focus Data Edited'!$K:$K,MATCH(1e99,'Focus Data Edited'!$K:$K))"
Range("H17").Formula = "=INDEX('Focus Data Edited'!$L:$L,MATCH(1e99,'Focus Data Edited'!$L:$L))"
Range("I17").Formula = "=INDEX('Focus Data Edited'!$M:$M,MATCH(1e99,'Focus Data Edited'!$M:$M))"
```

Let me know if you can help me!

Thanks, 
Hillary

Comment: What is the actual formula that's in the cells?

Comment: I use the formulas you posted, running your code, with dummie data and using `1e99` to get some results in the formulas, and work lick a charm. Please can you provide (some part of) the data you are using to try to help yo. For me everything is ok, but maybe we need more info.

Comment: I figured it out! I have another piece in my code that was deleting the tabs before the values were hard keyed.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the macro recorder in order to save your manual process.  Once you have saved your code, try to run it. If that works, you can slightly modify it to make it look better.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the OPs question